# How to safely eject usb hardrive - udisks returns "detach failed: .."

Tags: linux, usb, eject

I have a USB external hard drive with several partitions, and I cannot spin down the hard drive to get it to eject. Any suggestions? I unmounted all partitions through Nautilus, but the drive is still spinning. Nautilus does not seem to have other options besides `unmount` in Ubuntu 13.10.

After ensuring that no drives are mounted, I tried the `udisks` to detach the drive, but I get the following error:

```
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]~$ mount | grep ^'/dev'                                      
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]~$ udisks --detach /dev/sdb
Detach failed: One or more partitions are busy on /dev/sdb
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]~$
```

How can other partitions be busy if `mount | grep ^'/dev'` does not return any of my `/dev/sdb` partitions? Is there an easy way to detach my external hard drive? A simple solution would be nice...

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and my external hard drive is a backup my internal hard drive, setup via Clonezilla.

**UPDATE**
I tried `lsof`, results below:

```
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]~$ lsof /dev/sdb
sdb   sdb1  sdb2  sdb3  sdb4  sdb5  sdb6  
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]~$ lsof /dev/sdb
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]~$ lsof /dev/sdb1
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]~$ lsof /dev/sdb2
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]~$ lsof /dev/sdb3
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]~$ lsof /dev/sdb4
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]~$ lsof /dev/sdb5
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]~$ lsof /dev/sdb6
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]~$
```

Comment: Use `lsof` to see what is using the drive...

Comment: I just tried it, but my partitions are unmounted. Any ideas? I can still feel and hear my external HDD still spinnning! Should I just unplug it?

Comment: `lsof` usually doesn't print enough info if you are not root. Try `sudo lsof ...`. BTW do you use LVM, RAID, LUKS or any such device mapper?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```sh
$ sudo lsof /dev/sdb1
```

`lsof` will give you blank output without proper (root) permission to the drive.
If the backup program is not running, it's more than likely "ok" to disconnect.

Answer (score 1):

Device mapper or mdadm (RAID) could still be holding a partition open. The present-day setup of udev causes auto-recognition of RAID arrays, even if you don't try to mount or start them. So, for instance, if the disk was part of an array a long time ago, it might still have enough of the RAID signature that udev detected it. To check for that:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

To check for device mapper:

```
ls -l /sys/block/*/slaves/
```

Device mapper entries might be LVM, encrypted volumes, etc.